# Looking for a VPN capable router for a small business

Tags: router, osx

Looking to buy a VPN capable router, for less than 10 concurrent users. It needs to handle IPSec and have us be able to connect to it from both OS X and Windows clients.

Preferably it needs to work with Cisco AnyConnect but any router that allows us to obtain a certain ip/subnet after connecting to the vpn is fine.

We've tried using a Cisco RV042 with no luck.

Answer (score 1):

You can look at Ubiquiti's [EdgeMAX line](https://www.ubnt.com/products/#routing). Don't be fooled by the size and price, it is a very capable device. It can run standard IPsec and you can also install OpenVPN on it.

I have used OpenVPN for Windows and Unix machines with good results.

Comment: Do you think the EdgeRouterX is good enough? (https://www.ubnt.com/edgemax/edgerouter-x/)

Comment: I can't seem to find any info as too how many people are allowed at one time.

Comment: I think that EdgeRouterX will be good enough. It "allows" as many as you wish. There are no licensing restrictions, everything is open software. The hardware may be the only limit. Of course you won't get 1000Mbps VPN throughput, but I think that its performance will be enough for 10 users (at least it's worth trying for the price...).